# Python String split using comma before a specific string

Tags: python, regex

How to split using comma before a specific string and maxsplit=1 using python regex?
For Example here is a string:
Speciality: "Aesthetic Medicine, Oncology" , Profession:"Physician (MD, DO, Resident)"
I need to split this string at comma(,) right before "Profession".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

txt = 'Speciality: "Aesthetic Medicine, Oncology" , Profession: "Physician (MD, DO, Resident)"'

a = re.match('^(.*?),\s+(Profession:)(.*?)$', txt)

if(a):
#   print a.group(0)
    first = a.group(1)
    second = a.group(2)+a.group(3)
    print first
    print second
```

Output:

```
Speciality: "Aesthetic Medicine, Oncology" 
Profession: "Physician (MD, DO, Resident)"
```

Comment: thank you for the response. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @sameershiva check the V of my answer to close the issue